# could not make connection with hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

i am making connection with hive using java code but i am getting below error -

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException Permission denied: user=anonymous, access=WRITE, inode="/":oodles:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:271)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:257)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:238)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:179)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5904)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5886)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:5860)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:3793)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:3763)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3737)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:778)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:573)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)
>   )
>       at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:275)
>       at com.oodles.example.HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:23)

My Java code is below

```
package com.oodles.example;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class HiveJdbcClient {
    private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
        stmt.execute("drop table if exists " + tableName);
        stmt.execute("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
        System.out.println("success!");
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    }
}
```

and my other concern is that , whenever i make connection without starting hadoop services it gives error

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got exception: java.net.ConnectException Call From oodles-Latitude-3540/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:275)
    at com.oodles.example.HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:21)
```

later issue gets resolved if i start hadoop services ,so i want to ask is it mandatory to start hadoop services in order to make connection with hive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned what Hive version you are using, but base on the Driver name and connection URl I am assuming you are using Hive 0.11 or above.

So in Hive 0.11 or above you need to mention a username in the Connection URL:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", <user_name>, "")

NOTE: This user should have read+write permissions in HDFS.
```

Regarding you second query:

I am quite sure that Hadoop services are not required just for connection. I have never tried that.

Its my assumption, since we need to mention a database in the connection URL , which is a directory in HDFS. So it might need NAMENODE service to check the existence of that directory.

Hope it helps...!!!

Comment: Thanks Mukesh , but my query is "can't we make connection with hive without installing hadoop or having HDFS since we need namenode service to check the existence of that directory as u mention "

Comment: Even though you make Hive connection, at the end you need Hadoop because Hive uses HDFS and other hadoop services like Jobtracker to run its queries.